# Controller in MVC Architecture

Tags: controller

Please help me to choose 2 options from below which represents controller in MVC architecture?

- Custom Apex and Javascript code that is used to manipulate data
- StandardController system methods that are referenced by Visualforce
- Javascript that is used to make a menu item display itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Custom Apex and Javascript code that is used to manipulate data
- StandardController system methods that are referenced by Visualforce

Answer (score 2):

Seriously.. couldn't you at least make this look like a question you didn't copy out of a book? But it's

> Custom Apex and JavaScript code that is used to manipulate data, and Standardcontroller system methods that are reference by Visualforce